# How do I make a visited link change color on hover using CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How do I make a visited link change color on hover using CSS or JS

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a {
   color: blue;
}

a:visited {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you would style it using

```
a:visited:hover {
    styles go here
}
```